# How do I scan multiple txt files at the same time?

Tags: java

I am learning Java EE and am trying to scan multiple text files based on the option value listed in my code. If one of the three options is selected it will scan a corresponding text file and output some information.

As you can see I have it working to scan one file while obviously ignoring the option selection. I am not sure how to adjust my code to switch to a different file based on the selection.

I think I will have to move some things around such as moving the while loop inside of an if statement that implements the option choice, and then scan the file for the id which shouldn't be an issue. I am just kind of dumbfounded on reading from different txt files.

I have posted my code below so you can get an idea of what I am trying to do.

Should I create multiple scanners and implement it that way or should I do something else?

Edit: Thanks to a little bit of help I have managed to get it working. Here is the revised working code.

```
<body>
    <%
    String id = request.getParameter("id");        
    String cid = request.getParameter("classID");
    String[] title = {"Name: ", "SSN: ", "Score: "};
    Scanner sc;        
    %>

    Find Your Current Score.
    <%-- Blank space here --%>
    <p></p>
    <%-- Input Forms (Text Field and Button) --%>
    <form action="ScoreFinder.jsp" method="get">
    Employee ID:
    <input type="text" name="id"/> Use SSN Format: xxx-xxx-xxxx
    <p></p>
    Class:
    <select name="classID">
    <option value="CMIS440">CMIS 440</option>
    <option value="CMIS445">CMIS 445</option>
    <option value="CMIS485">CMIS 485</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>

    <%
        if (id != null || cid != null) {
            String fileName = "/"+cid.replaceAll(" ", "") + ".txt";
            sc = new Scanner(new File(application.getRealPath(fileName)));
            while(sc.hasNext()) {                
            String line = sc.nextLine();
            String[] split = line.split("[#]");
            if (id.length() == 0) {
                out.println("Please enter an ID number.");
                break;
            }
            if (line.contains(id)) {
                out.println("Class: " + cid);
                %><br><%
                for (int i=0; i<split.length; i++){
                    out.println(title[i]);
                    out.println(split[i]);
                    %><br><%
                }
                break;
            }
            }
        }%>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your listed JSP's name is ScoreFinder.jsp and you are submitting records to the same JSP.

You can create the name of text file from the value of parameter `id` e.g.

```
<body>
    <%
    String id = request.getParameter("id");
    String fileName = "/"+id.replaceAll(" ", "")+".txt"; // avoiding null check of 'id' for simplicity
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(application.getRealPath(fileName)));
    try {
        while(sc.hasNext()) {

    ........
    ........
```

Comment: My JSP name is ScoreFinder.jsp. By submitting records, do you mean attempting to retrieve information from the text file or actually populating the text file?

If you are talking about retrieving information then this is exactly what I am trying to do.

However, looking at the code you posted, it seems that this should work either way as long as I adjust it to work off of the Class_ID relevant to the text file.

Comment: I have updated my code here with the changes that I have made. After implementing the changes I am presented with a null pointer exception. The files are there, not sure what is going on.

Comment: Yes, you get it in a right way. For NullPointerException either share stacktace or check the value of `id` and `classID` parameters for null value.

Comment: I have added a stacktrace (the reference of line 69 is the "String fileName" line) to my post. Also, if you look at the values of classID you can see that the files in question should be named CMIS440, CMIS445 and CMIS485 respectively, which is how they are named.

Comment: As you said line#69 is "String fileName..." then `cid` must be null. To debug you should Sysout its value. Also check browser URL after submitting values for "classID" parameter. Is it same as it is in Sysout.

Comment: Ok, so I have updated my code. I no longer get the nullpointerexception, now I can actually get to the interface, however, whenever i input any information and click submit, nothing happens other than the address bar updating. If I change "classID" to cid and save the file while running live, it will fetch the information from the text file. If I try to reload the file after that it goes back to nullpointer.

Comment: This is because you are comparing one string CONSTANT to another string CONSTANT which will always be false  _if (**"classID"**.equalsIgnoreCase(**"cmis440.txt"**)) {_ , like wise in _else if (**"classID"**.equalsIgnoreCase(**"cmis445.txt"**)) {_ . Use `cid.equalsIgnoreCase("cmis440.txt")`

Comment: `cid.equalsIgnoreCase("cmis440.txt")`  did not work. I tried running it through both glassfish and tomcat with several different variations, one being the one that was posted earlier. However, tomcat gave me more pinpoint errors and it helped me to tweak it until I got it just right. Your code to set the variable was very useful as well. Thank you for your help.